# Hiding Twitter tokens in Perl

Tags: perl, twitter, oauth

I'm writing a Perl script that posts on Twitter the current playing song in MPD.

In order to do that I need to insert the application's consumer_key and consumer_secret.

If I want to release the code how should I hide these tokens?

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/ZNVdqu36

Comment: I have rewritten by 0 the code. http://pastebin.com/8x91HfUG
Now I'm using the username/password auth as documented here http://search.cpan.org/~mmims/Net-Twitter-Lite-0.10004/lib/Net/Twitter/Lite.pm#BASIC_AUTHENTICATION, but I obtain this:
`~/Sources/mpdtweet% ./mpdtweet2.pl`
`Tweeting «#nowplaying King Crimson - Pictures Of A City (In The Wake Of Poseidon)».`
`401: Unauthorized`

**EDIT** Okay, I can't use it: https://github.com/semifor/Net-Twitter/wiki/Net::Twitter-and-the-death-of-Basic-Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the key in the code so that noone will be able to get it out. Not in Perl, not elsewhere.

Your application has to send the code to Twitter, so it has to be able to get the code itself. This means any decent hacker who's a bit motivated can get it too.

[davorg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133497/hiding-twitter-tokens-in-perl/9139933#9139933) illustrates this point as well, but you can't really use that when you have to distribute the app to your customer: either he checks his environment variables, or just adds a print statement that output the twitter

Answer (score 0):

Make them environment variables.

```
unless ($ENV{TWITTER_KEY} and $ENV{TWITTER_SECRET}) {
  die "Please set the environment variables TWITTER_KEY and TWITTER_SECRET\n";
}

my $twitter = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(
        consumer_key    => $ENV{TWITTER_KEY},
        consumer_secret => $ENV{TWITTER_SECRET},
);
```